# hivemr3 on kubernetes: worker pod stack at Init:0/1 status

Tags: kubernetes, hive

i installed hive using this tutorial (https://mr3docs.datamonad.com/docs/quick/k8s/run-k8s/). The pods are working fine, i can create databases, tables.. BUT when i need to insert data in a table a worker pod is created but it's never running ( stack at Init:0/1  status ), when i describe the worker pod, i get this [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vMsJa.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The directories listed in mr3.k8s.pod.worker.hostpaths should be available on every worker node. In you case, it seems that /data1/k8s to /data6/k8s are not found on worker nodes, or they are not directories.

Comment: You'right, i didn't have these directories in the worker nodes. I resolved this problem by adding this  mr3.k8s.pod.worker.emptydirs = /opt/mr3-run/work-local-dir. and mr3.k8s.pod.worker.hostpaths is set to empty.   Thank you for your reply